# Substitution rules do not trigger

Tags: function-construction, replacement, expression-manipulation

I am trying to write substitution rules to obtain an ordered 4-form from four 1-forms constructed by applying a total differentiation to four functions:

```
ClearAll[form]
form[x___, z_, y___] /; ! (Head[z] == Dt) := Module[{vrs, rls, i},
  vrs = Cases[z, _Dt, {-2}] // Union;
  rls = (#[[1]].vrs -> #[[2]] &) /@ CoefficientRules[z, vrs];
  Sum[(vrs[[i]] /. rls) form[x, vrs[[i]], y], {i, 1, Length[vrs]}]
  ]
form[x___, Dt[q1_], w___, Dt[q1_], y___] := 0
form[x___,Dt[q2_],Dt[q1_],y___] /;!({q2, q1}===Sort[{q2, q1}]):=-form[x, Dt[q1], Dt[q2], y]
```

Trying the input:

```
form[Dt[(a + b c)/d], Dt[(a - b c)/d], Dt[(d + b a)/c], Dt[d - b a]]
```

> `form[(Dt[a] + c Dt[b] + b Dt[c])/d - ((a + b c) Dt[d])/d^2, (
>     Dt[a] - c Dt[b] - b Dt[c])/d - ((a - b c) Dt[d])/
>     d^2, -(((a b + d) Dt[c])/c^2) + (b Dt[a] + a Dt[b] + Dt[d])/
>     c, -b Dt[a] - a Dt[b] + Dt[d]]`

Does apparently nothing. I would have expected the first rule defined above to decompose all entries of `form` to contain only `Dt[x_]` terms and the remaining two rules to sort these entries. Why do the substitutions not trigger? How should I fix it so it does what I'm trying to implement?

**EDIT:**

Fixed my code, so that now it works as well:

```
ClearAll[form]
form[{x___}] := form[x];
form[x___, z_, y___] /; ! (Head[z] === Dt) := Module[{vrs, rls, i}, 
  vrs = Cases[z, _Dt, {-2}] // Union;
  rls = (#[[1]].vrs -> #[[2]] &) /@ CoefficientRules[z, vrs];
  Sum[(vrs[[i]] /. rls) form[x, vrs[[i]], y], {i, 1, Length[vrs]}]
  ]
form[x___, q1_, w___, q1_, y___] := 0
form[x___, q2_, q1_, y___] /; ! ({q2, q1} === Sort[{q2, q1}]) := -form[x, q1, q2, y]
```

Comment: What happens if you use `/; Head[z] =!= Dt` in the first line?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Wow, yes, now the first rule triggers, but the other two do not...

Comment: You are aware that by naming two appearances of a pattern both `q1` you force them to match an identical expression?  (I'm just looking for possible issues and not running nor attempting to fully understand this code.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, $...\wedge x\wedge ...\wedge x\wedge ...=0$ due to antisymmetry of the wedge product in a $p$-form.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see anything else to question and the moment and I'm signing off for the day.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you for your help so far! It was very useful to me. :) Have an enjoyable rest of the day!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you can make use of [`TensorProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorProduct) and [`TensorExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorExpand). I also took the liberty of using [`Wedge`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Wedge) (a symbol with no built-in meaning) instead of `form`:

```
Clear[Wedge];
Wedge[a__] := Module[{tp, exp, scalars},
   scalars = DeleteCases[Variables[{a}], _Dt];
   Assuming[Element[Alternatives @@ scalars, Arrays[{}]],
      tp = TensorProduct[a];
      exp = TensorExpand[tp]
   ];
   (
      exp /. TensorProduct -> Wedge
   ) /; tp =!= exp
];
Wedge[___, a_, ___, a_, ___] = 0;
Wedge[a__] /; Sort[{a}] =!= {a} := Signature[{a}] Wedge @@ Sort[{a}]
```

In the definition of [`Wedge`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Wedge), I used `Element[.., Arrays[{}]]` to declare non-`Dt[__]` variables as scalars, and I used [`Signature`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Signature) instead of pairwise swaps to reorder the [`Wedge`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Wedge) forms. For the OP's example:

```
Wedge[Dt[(a+b c)/d], Dt[(a-b c)/d], Dt[(d+b a)/c], Dt[d-b a]] //TeXForm
```

> $-\frac{4 a^2 b^2 da\wedge db\wedge dc\wedge dd}{c d^3}+\frac{2 a b da\wedge db\wedge
>    dc\wedge dd}{c d^2}+\frac{2 da\wedge db\wedge dc\wedge dd}{c d}$

Comment: This is great, thank you!